# undefined method when trying to render params from a different Model with belongs_to assoc

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to render values of model **Billingitem** within the model **Invoice** view - I'm working with Rails 4.1 so I have included them as strong params within the Controller like:

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController

  private
    def invoice_params
      params.fetch(:invoice, {}).permit(:issue_time, :total, :vat_id, :amount,
          :item, :currency, :client_id, :invoice, :quarter, :pdf, 
          :recurringmonthly, :recurringbiweekly, :expense,
          billingitems_attributes: [ :id, :name, :quantity, :price ])
    end

end
```

The associations are in the Models too:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :billingitems
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :billingitems

end
```

and

```
class Billingitem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice
end
```

While in the console I can see the values correctly (for instance > Invoice.find(76).billingitems.name and returns a value ) if I try to do the same with any other param like Invoice.find(76).billingitems.quantity or Invoice.find(76).billingitems.price I always get `undefined method price` or `undefined method quantity` in the console and in the view. Why?

Comment: `Invoice.find(76).billingitems`, `billingitems` is a collection in `Invoice`, you can't call those methods in the collection itself, you need to call them in an instance of the collection, try perhaps: `Invoice.find(76).billingitems.first.price`, `Invoice.find(76).billingitems.first.quantity`, etc., etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @fanta said billingitems is a collection. so you should do something like this

```
Invoice.find(76).billingitems.each do |billingitem|
  billingitem.name
  billingitem.quantity
  billingitem.price
end
```